# Could use some pointers to create dat file from sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, file

I could use some pointers on my query I have three external tables that i need to combine and create a .dat-file. But my query isn't very efficient and could use some help on fixing/improving this one. It consist of two part one main table which is dc_item_loc_sourcing (1) and two translation tables dc_ccn190_sid_vtb(2) and dc_item_loc_vert_pim(3). If the item + loc combination doesn't exist in 1 & 2 it should check 1 & 3.

```
SET heading OFF;    
SET feedback OFF; 
SET verify OFF; 
SET echo OFF;
SET linesize 1000;  
SET trimspool ON;
SET termout OFF;
SET newpage NONE;
SPOOL ../data/dc_sourcing.dat; 

SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(item)
  || '|' ||store
  || '|' ||source_method
  || '|' ||primary_supp
  || '|' ||source_wh
  || '|' ||actie
  || '|' ||reward_eligible_ind
FROM ((SELECT dpac_tbl.item
      ,st.store
      ,dc_iloc.source_method
      ,dc_iloc.primary_supp
      ,dc_iloc.source_wh
      ,dc_iloc.actie
      ,dc_iloc.reward_eligible_ind
      ,MAX(dc_iloc.source_method) OVER (PARTITION BY dpac_tbl.item,st.store) max_src_pack
    FROM dc_item_loc_sourcing dc_iloc ,
      dc_ccn190_sid_vtb dpac_tbl ,
      store st ,
      item_master im ,
      item_loc il
    WHERE dc_iloc.dpac                         = dpac_tbl.dpac
    AND dpac_tbl.item                          = im.item
    AND CAST(dc_iloc.loc AS VARCHAR2(150byte)) = st.store_name_secondary
    AND st.store                               = il.loc
    AND dpac_tbl.item                          = il.item
    AND im.status                              = 'A'
    AND st.store_close_date                   >= SYSDATE
    AND il.status                              = 'A'
    AND dpac_tbl.ITEM NOT                     IN
      (SELECT IA.ITEM
      FROM ITEM_ATTRIBUTES IA
      WHERE IA.SH_STORE_ORDER_UNIT = 'N'
      AND IA.SH_TRADE_UNIT         = 'Y')
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT pi.item
      ,st.store
      ,dc_iloc.source_method
      ,dc_iloc.primary_supp
      ,dc_iloc.source_wh
      ,dc_iloc.actie
      ,dc_iloc.reward_eligible_ind
          ,MAX(dc_iloc.source_method) OVER (PARTITION BY pi.item,st.store) max_src_pack
    FROM dc_item_loc_sourcing dc_iloc ,
      dc_ccn190_sid_vtb dpac_tbl ,
      store st ,
      packitem pi ,
      item_master im ,
      item_loc il
    WHERE dc_iloc.dpac                         = dpac_tbl.dpac
    AND pi.pack_no                             = dpac_tbl.item
    AND pi.item                                = im.item
    AND CAST(dc_iloc.loc AS VARCHAR2(150byte)) = st.store_name_secondary
    AND il.item                                = pi.item
    AND il.loc                                 = st.store
    AND im.status                              = 'A'
    AND im.dept NOT                           IN (900,910,920,930)
    AND st.store_close_date                   >= SYSDATE
    AND il.status                              = 'A'
    AND PI.ITEM NOT                           IN
      (SELECT IA.ITEM
      FROM ITEM_ATTRIBUTES IA
      WHERE IA.SH_STORE_ORDER_UNIT = 'N'
      AND IA.SH_TRADE_UNIT         = 'Y'))
UNION
      (SELECT dpac_tbl.item ,
      st.store ,
      dc_iloc.source_method ,
      dc_iloc.primary_supp ,
      dc_iloc.source_wh ,
      dc_iloc.actie ,
      dc_iloc.reward_eligible_ind
      ,MAX(dc_iloc.source_method) OVER (PARTITION BY dpac_tbl.item,st.store) max_src_pack
    FROM dc_item_loc_sourcing dc_iloc ,
      dc_item_loc_vert_pim dpac_tbl ,
      store st ,
      item_master im ,
      item_loc il
    WHERE dc_iloc.dpac                          = dpac_tbl.dpac
    AND dpac_tbl.item                           = im.item
    AND CAST(dc_iloc.loc AS VARCHAR2(150 byte)) = st.store_name_secondary
    AND il.item                                 = dpac_tbl.item
    AND il.loc                                  = st.store
    AND im.status                               = 'A'
    AND dpac_tbl.artikel_type_lms NOT          IN ('V','S')
    AND st.store_close_date                    >= SYSDATE
    AND il.status                               = 'A'
    AND inventory_item_status_code             = 'Active'
    AND dpac_tbl.ITEM NOT                      IN
      (SELECT IA.ITEM
      FROM ITEM_ATTRIBUTES IA
      WHERE IA.SH_STORE_ORDER_UNIT = 'N'
      AND IA.SH_TRADE_UNIT         = 'Y')
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT pi.item ,
      st.store ,
      dc_iloc.source_method ,
      dc_iloc.primary_supp ,
      dc_iloc.source_wh ,
      dc_iloc.actie ,
      dc_iloc.reward_eligible_ind
          ,MAX(dc_iloc.source_method) OVER (PARTITION BY pi.item,st.store) max_src_pack

    FROM dc_item_loc_sourcing dc_iloc ,
      dc_item_loc_vert_pim dpac_tbl ,
      store st ,
      packitem pi ,
      item_master im ,
      item_loc il
    WHERE dc_iloc.dpac                          = dpac_tbl.dpac
    AND pi.pack_no                              = dpac_tbl.item
    AND pi.item                                 = im.item
    AND CAST(dc_iloc.loc AS VARCHAR2(150 byte)) = st.store_name_secondary
    AND il.item                                 = pi.item
    AND il.loc                                  = st.store
    AND im.status                               = 'A'
    AND dpac_tbl.artikel_type_lms NOT          IN ('V','S')
    AND im.dept NOT                            IN (900,910,920,930)
    AND st.store_close_date                    >= SYSDATE 
    AND il.status                               = 'A'
    AND inventory_item_status_code             = 'Active'
    AND pi.ITEM NOT                            IN
      (SELECT IA.ITEM
      FROM ITEM_ATTRIBUTES IA
      WHERE IA.SH_STORE_ORDER_UNIT = 'N'
      AND IA.SH_TRADE_UNIT         = 'Y'))) 
    WHERE source_method = max_src_pack;


SPOOL OFF;
```

Comment: To be sure, this query appears to have improvement possibilities (although it may take a while to wade through).  But some queries are going to take a while to run, no matter what you do - I've got multiple that take over an hour (and some 5 or 6) that take that long, just because of the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hasn't been tested - I'm away from an SQL instance at the moment, and obviously I don't have access to your tables.  I also don't make any guarantee about performance, as I don't know about current indicies.

Your biggest problem appears to stem from using the implicit-join syntax.  Don't use it, it's an anti-pattern; it also allows for some 'surprising' behaviour.  Always explicitly specify your joins, and put (as many as possible) relevant conditions in the `ON` clause - only use the `WHERE` clause when dealing with the table reference in the `FROM` clause.

I also have a huge problem with this line:
`AND CAST(dc_iloc.loc AS VARCHAR2(150byte)) = st.store_name_secondary`
You will *not* (likely... there are some caveats) be using an index on this comparison, which won't help.  It's also a terrible thing, semantically, to join on - why is an item-location table keyed by (apparently) the store name?  It **should** by keyed by store id - which should be the same datatype (no conversions), and should be the internal id, not something as transient as a 'name'.

```
WITH Excluded_Item (item) as (SELECT DISTINCT item
                              FROM Item_Attributes
                              WHERE sh_store_order_unit = 'N'
                              AND sh_trade_unit = 'Y'), -- These should be 1/0 flags
                                                        -- (char or numeric)
                                                        -- or boolean, if supported

SELECT CAST(item as CHAR) 
       || '|' || loc 
       || '|' || source_method 
       || '|' || primary_supp 
       || '|' || source_wh 
       || '|' || actie 
       || '|' || reward_eligible_ind 

FROM(SELECT DISTINCT c.item, c.loc,
                     a.source_method, a.primary_supp, a.source_wh, a.actie,
                     a.reward_eligible_ind,
                     MAX(a.source_method) 
                     OVER(PARTITION BY c.item, c.loc) as maxSourcePack
                                 -- this should be indexed
     FROM dc_item_loc_sourcing as a
     JOIN store as b
     ON b.store_name_secondary = CAST(a.loc as VARCHAR2(150 byte))
     AND b.store_close_date >= CURRENT_DATE
     JOIN item_loc as c
     ON c.loc = b.store
     AND c.status = 'A'
     JOIN item_master as d
     ON d.status = 'A'
     AND d.item = c.item
     LEFT JOIN Excluded_Item as e
     ON e.item = d.item
     LEFT JOIN dc_ccn190_sid_vtb as f
     ON f.dpac = a.dpac
     LEFT JOIN dc_item_loc_vert_pim as g
     ON g.dpac = a.dpac
     AND g.artikel_type_lms NOT IN ('V', 'S')
     AND inventory_item_status_code = 'Active' -- really?  And where is this from? 
     LEFT JOIN packitem as h
     ON (h.pack_no = f.item OR h.pack_no = g.item)
     AND h.item = d.item
     AND d.dept NOT IN (900, 910, 920, 930)
     WHERE e.item IS NULL
     AND (h.item IS NOT NULL
          OR (h.item IS NULL AND (f.item = d.item OR g.item = d.item))) ) as h

WHERE source_method = maxSourcepack
```

I *believe* this is correct, although a definition of your tables (and sample data) would help immensely in this regard - especially in how `packitem` is defined.

Comment: the store_name can either contain a name or an id, but the names have already been filter out in a query before this. The inventory_item_status_code is a value from the table dc_item_loc_vert_pim. Thanx for the help it's really helpful :-)